# combobox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener is triggered twice in javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, combobox, javafx-2

I populated the combobox with the help of a observablearraylist in javafx. removing items from list yields --Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException-- and the event is triggered twice

Comment: UnsupportedOperationException implies you're using a read-only list, like Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");... could you post your code that populates the combobox...?

Comment: ObservableList<String> items=FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<String>()); combobox.setItems(items);

Comment: That should be OK... could you post the full Exception trace... ? particularly the top few lines... and also your call to remove() in context...

Comment: I am able to understand why it is triggered twice because i'm adding and removing items to list in the add listener method itself. but how should i implement it? can any one quote an example where i can update (i.e, adding and deleting items) the combo box upon selecting an item. Changes are done to the combo box based on the selected item.